# Probability of "At least one" with replacement

Tags: probability, sampling

For a given set $S$ with $N$ element:
$$S=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_N\}$$
we create another set $S'$ by choosing randomly $N$ elements from set $S$ with replacement:
$$S' = \{x_1,x_1,x_2...,x_N\}$$
What percentage of elements of $S$ will occur at least once in $S'$, on average, if: $N=10$.

What I have tried is the following: To find at least one we have to do

$$P(x) = 1 - (\frac{(N-1)}{N})^N$$

based on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639625/probability-of-drawing-a-card-at-least-once-with-replacement/1639628#1639628).

Now how can I find the percentage of all elements of $S$ that will occur at least once in the $S'$ set?

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements of $S$ that appear [at least once] in $S'$ can be written as
$$I_1 + \cdots + I_n$$
where $I_j=\begin{cases} 1 & x_j \in S' \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then use $E[I_1 + \cdots + I_n] = E[I_1] + \cdots + E[I_n]$. The terms on the right-hand side will be related to the computation you have already done. (It is not clear to me if $n \ne N$ or if you made a typo.)

Comment: $n=N$ it was a typo. Could you please elaborate on what exactly is this part $E[I_1]$ what does it actually point to?

Comment: @flowcyan $E[I_j]$ is the expectation of the indicator random variable $I_j$ I defined above. It is 
equivalent to the probability that $x_j$ appears in $S'$.

Comment: So basically to find that is $10* (1-(\frac{N-1}{N})^N)$?

Comment: How can I solve for $E[I_1]$?

Comment: @flowcyan You got it

Comment: Have you done some editing? I don't see anything?

Comment: @flowcyan Sorry, I meant that $N ( 1 - (\frac{N-1}{N})^N)$ is correct.